# Is addInCondition() method in CDbCriteria "SQL-injection proof"?

Tags: php, yii, prepared-statement, yii-cactiverecord

I wanna use CDbCriteira addInCondition() for multiple input parameters (number is not predefined). Does this method compose parametrized query or not?
I found controversial thoughts on this:

1. [yes](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13119-sql-injection-question/page__view__findpost__p__122789)  - "Since it uses CDbCriteria I would assume it to be safe" - quote.
2. [no](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24243-security-mysq-injection/page__view__findpost__p__117662)

Also I've looked at [the addInCondition() method specification](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/db/schema/CDbCriteria.php#L274) and i couldn't get clear though.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

```
$condition=$column.'='.self::PARAM_PREFIX.self::$paramCount;
$this->params[self::PARAM_PREFIX.self::$paramCount++]=$value;
```

Seems to be for storing parametrized values.

Then in a Query Builder, it will use them as numerated parameters.

I do that way in a script I made myself, I really doubt Qian (or whatever) would miss it and leave a code injection.

Also, DID YOU TEST IT? You could add random SQL and see if it gets escaped.

Comment: i didn't test, since i couldn't break so far to bind string parameters (unknown in number).